# 2002 Chevrolet headlights problem

Tags: chevrolet, troubleshooting, headlight

I installed HID headlights a while back, but I'm not sure if it's part of the problem. The low beams in my 2002 Chevrolet do not turn on correctly. Here's what's happening...

On the **Low Beam** setting:

- Passenger Side:

  - Low Beam - **On**
  - High Beam - On
- Driver's Side:

  - Low Beam - **Off**
  - High Beam - On

On the **High Beam** setting:

- Passenger Side:

  - Low Beam - Off
  - High Beam - On
- Driver's Side:

  - Low Beam - Off
  - High Beam - On

    1. What could be causing this?
    2. How do I diagnose this?

Comment: Sounds like you need to rewire  your HIDs.

Comment: Usually low and high beam are both on when hitting the signal high beam, when just enabling high beam, the low beam should be off. This might make a difference for you.